# How to output the contents of a variable to a newline using sed

Tags: sed

> PING=$(ping -c 2 google.com)
>
> sed -i.bak "s/test:/&\n$PING/g" test.txt

*Im trying to output the variable PING on a newline after test: in the test.txt file.
But i keep receiving this error.*

> sed: -e expression #1, char 64: unterminated `s' command

I don't know where I'm going wrong any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can write sed scripts like you write bash scripts, and newlines are command separators. you need a line continuation.

untested:

```
sed "s/test/&\
$PING/g" file
```

Style advice: get out of the habit of using UPPERCASE variable names. One day you'll use PATH and break your script.